# Greater than and less than operators at statistics

Tags: statistics

line 1: ${Fj|j=1,..,N}$

line 2: $S= \sum_{j=1}^{N} F_{j}$

I can understand above lines 1 and 2, sum of an element serial.

But what is below line 3

line 3: $<S>=< \sum_{j=1}^{N} F_{j}> = \sum_{j=1}^{N} <F_{j}>$

I understand greater than and less than symbols tells mean, average.

Am i right?

I know average or mean with a restricted perspective.

I understand mean or average as: "the sum of elements is divided by element count"

Am i right?

If i am right what is mean of a sum : $<S>=< \sum_{j=1}^{N} F_{j}>$ ?

Does $<S>=< \sum_{j=1}^{N} F_{j}>$ tell $<S>= (\sum_{j=1}^{N} F_{j})/N$

I know my understanding is poor, any perspective whould be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes less than and greater than sign represents the mean, for details solution is [here](http://www.4shared.com/download/W-78IuHq/123456.bmp?tsid=20130728-035931-8f7dec06)